# Result percentage by period in SQL

Tags: sql, percentage, period

I want to calculate result percentage in SQL from the this data for a each period.

```
Period  Result
1        Green
1        Blue
1        Blue
1        Red
1        Blue
1        Blue
1        Blue
2        Green 
2        Green 
2        Green
2        Blue
2        Red
2        Red
```

Expected result ..

```
Period  Result  Percentage
1        Blue     72%
1        Green    9%
1        Red      9%
2        Blue     17%
2        Green    50%
2        Red      33%
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT` by `Period` first, join the result with the original table again, grouped by both `Period` and `Result`, and then just do a division to obtain the percentage:

```
SELECT t.Period, t.Result, ((COUNT(t.Result) / Cnt) * 100) Percentage
FROM table t 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Period, COUNT(*) Cnt
                 FROM table
                 GROUP BY Period) period_cnt 
     ON t.Period = period_cnt.Period
GROUP BY t.Period, t.Result
```

You may need to adjust the rounding, and use `CONCAT` to add the character `%` to your output, but that should be fairly easy.

Also, your *average* for the first period is wrong, it should add up to `100`. Green and Red should have the value `14`.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c224d0/9)**.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (ANSI SQL):

```
select period,
       result,
       (count(result) / total_period) * 100 as result_percent
from (
  select period, 
         result,
         count(*) over (partition by period) as total_period
  from periods  
) as t
group by period, total_period, result
order by period, result;
```

Depending on your DBMS you might need to cast the integer values to a decimal in order to see fractional values.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2ec4f/1